# How to access standard Salesforce labels in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, label

I know how to access my own custom labels, that is explained [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_labels).

But how to access the standard Salesforce labels, e.g. for Save and Cancel buttons? I want to use those, because my org uses internationalization, so being able to use the standard labels and their translations would save a lot of time. But how to access them?

I have tried

```
import saveBtnLabel from '@salesforce/label/c.save';
```

and

```
import saveBtnLabel from '@salesforce/label/site.save';
```

but neither of them work.

Comment: I think you need to create custom labels for that.